# How to remove parent element and keep its child elements without creating empty span

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<span >I</span>
<span > </span>
<span class="highlight">
<span >l</span>
<span >i</span>
<span >v</span>
<span >e</span>
<span > </span>
</span>
<span >h</span>
<span >e</span>
<span >r</span>
<span >e</span>
```

I want to remove the element with class ="highlight" and keep its child element. What I did is `toRemove.outerHTML = toRemove.innerHTML;`, it works fine, but when I check the updated HTML, it creates empty span element surrounding "live". Is there any way to remove parent element and keep its child element without creating empty span element? Thanks.

UPDATE: Thanks for all your answers. What if I only allow to use pure Javascript, not Jquery to do this?

Comment: As you have tagged jquery, have a look at using [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Comment: `toRemove` is undefined. or is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to insert the children elements after your wrapping element to maintain the position. Then [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) or [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the wrapper.

```js
$('#fixit').on('click', function(e) {
  var $highlight = $('.highlight');
  var $children = $highlight.children();
  $children.insertAfter($highlight);
  $highlight.remove();
  
});
```

```css
body > span {
 background-color: gold;
}
.highlight {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span >I</span>
<span > </span>
<span class="highlight">
  <span >l</span>
  <span >i</span>
  <span >v</span>
  <span >e</span>
  <span > </span>
</span>
<span >h</span>
<span >e</span>
<span >r</span>
<span >e</span>
<button id="fixit">Fix it</button>
```

If you use [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove the the element you could store it in a variable to reattach it later if you need to "revert the changes" and keeping a reference to the children as well to add it after again.

```js
+function() {
  var $highlight = null;
  var $children = null;
  $('#fixit').on('click', function(e) {
    if($highlight == null) {
      $highlight = $('.highlight');
      $children = $highlight.children();
      $children.insertAfter($highlight);
      $highlight.detach();
      }
    else {
       /** get the first child position, otherwise there are four wrappers **/
       $highlight.insertAfter($children.first());
       $highlight.append($children);
       $children = null;
       $highlight = null;
    }
  });
}();
```

```css
body > span {
 background-color: gold;
}
.highlight {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span >I</span>
<span > </span>
<span class="highlight">
  <span >l</span>
  <span >i</span>
  <span >v</span>
  <span >e</span>
  <span > </span>
</span>
<span >h</span>
<span >e</span>
<span >r</span>
<span >e</span>
<button id="fixit">Fix it</button>
```

A pure JS solution as requested in the comments:

```js
var fixit = document.getElementById('fixit');
fixit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // get all elements with marker class. 
  var highlights = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
  if(highlights.length) {
    // iterate them all
    for(c = 0; c < highlights.length;c++) {

        var highlight = highlights[c];
        var children = highlight.children;
        // get all the children, last first then add them to parent so order is preserved
        for(i = children.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            highlight.parentNode.insertBefore(children[i], highlight.nextSibling);
        }
    }
    // remove the marked elment.
    highlight.parentNode.removeChild(highlight);
  }
  
});
```

```css
body > span {
 background-color: gold;
}
.highlight {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span >I</span>
<span > </span>
<span class="highlight">
  <span >l</span>
  <span >i</span>
  <span >v</span>
  <span >e</span>
  <span > </span>
</span>
<span >h</span>
<span >e</span>
<span >r</span>
<span >e</span>
<button id="fixit">Fix it</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works. What if I only want to use pure Javascript, what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: I added a pure js solution at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> **unwrap():** Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

You could simply use the jQuery method **[`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** like :

```
 $(toRemove).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get Get the children of each element , including text and comment nodes.

You can do something like this:

```js
var data = $(".highlight").contents();
$(".highlight").replaceWith(data);
```

```css
.highlight { background-color:blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span >I</span>
<span > </span>
<span class="highlight">
<span >l</span>
<span >i</span>
<span >v</span>
<span >e</span>
<span > </span>
</span>
<span >h</span>
<span >e</span>
<span >r</span>
<span >e</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the original after saving a copy of its' children and put the children back after the appropriate element. (Or before or whatever you feel like.)

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/513654/

```
var highlight = $(".highlight");

var children = highlight.children()

highlight.remove()

$('span').each(function(i,e){
  if (i == 1)
  $(this).after(children);
});
```